# Javascript custom onread events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to somehow catch an event when the data is being read from the DOM. For instance, `textarea.value`, `div.innerHTML` and etc. I tried somehow override these prototype properties, but with no success, it's not that simple like overriding prototype methods.

Did anyone encounter this problem and find solution? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So, in other words you want to fire a custom event on any property's `get` accessor?

Comment: Hmmmm... I'll have a think! Not sure this can be done though - property accessors are easily bypassed (intentionally or not) in Javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found this [interesting article by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) which suggests it can be done. I put together [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HwYm8/) as a test and it seems to work, however I haven't tried extending this for use on DOM object properties yet. Also, I'm not sure quite how cross-browser it is, but maybe it could help give you some ideas to explore?

Comment: Tnx @chris. The lookup(Getter|Setter) is actually the answer. You get the pointer to the function that implements the specified property. You can then save it somewhere, then with __define(Getter|Setter)__ define the property with same name, thus override it and use the previous functionality if needed. This was actually the thing I needed. I wanted to keep the functionality, but to make some additional logging.

Comment: Awesome, I'm definitely bookmarking this - could solve a lot of problems in future!

Comment: Did anyone tried it Webkit, because it doesn't seem to work. Is there maybe a workaround?